# How to customize community user login page of salesforce mobile sdk-react native app

Tags: community, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, mobilesdk

Steps to reproduce:

1. Community user login with specific url (Login page is **Experience Builder Page**)
2. login successfully and redirect to login page instead of home page

Expected:

1. Community user login with specific url, login successfully and redirect to home page

Solution:

1. Change the Login page to **Default page**

Questions:

1. How to customize the login page?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official document, Reference this link: `https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.mobile_sdk.meta/mobile_sdk/auth_customize_login.htm`